# Override service mapping settings in structureMap

Tags: structuremap

Can I override service mapping for StructureMap settings of added registry:

```
    return new Container(x => { 
        For<IService>().Use<OverridenService>
        x.AddRegistry<MyRegistry>();
        For<IService>().Use<OverridenService>
     }

public class MyRegistry: Registry   
{   
    public MyRegistry()
    { 
       For<IService>().Use<MyService>
    }
}
```

I want OverridenService to be instantiated, but StructureMap instantiates MyService always

Answer (score 0):

So, let's say you have this code (this code assigns the container to a variable that you can later return):

```
var container = new Container(x =>
{
    x.AddRegistry<MyRegistry>();
});
```

You can simply use the `Configure` method like this:

```
container.Configure(x => x.For<IService>().Use<OverridenService>());
```